# VirtoCommerce Store Front Where dose it get the data

Tags: c#, e-commerce, virtocommerce

Hello VirtoCommrece People its an honor working with such product, 
 its a bit complex to me at my level so please forgive me if im asking some basic newbe questions , 
how dose the data comes from the platfrom to the api ? 
i tried to delete the _workcontext from the index action nothing happen 
i deleted the angular services the images gone but the data stayed so can anyone tell me 
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can understand, you're interesting in how data comes from platform to storefront. Storefront has auto-generated code (by AutoRest util from Microsoft) to call platform RESTful API from C#. This APIs called via frontend user with special api key. You can find more info here:

- [Working with Platform API](https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide/development-scenarios/working-with-platform-api)
- [How to generate module API C# client using AutoRest](https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide/development-scenarios/how-to-generate-module-api-c-sharp-client-using-autorest)